# How to scroll within PowerPoint slide with keyboard / working with big slides

Tags: keyboard, mouse, microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling

My company loves Microsoft products, therefore I am now forced to prepare a conference poster with PowerPoint. That means I have a single large slide in my presentation. Due to the size of the poster, I am almost always working on some zoomed part of the slide. The problem is that three most important "computer" functions do not work in this mode in PP (or I don't know how to make them work):

1. I cannot scroll by pressing up, down, PageUp, PageDown keys;
2. When zooming with Ctrl+mouse wheel, zooming happens with respect to the slide centre, not the mouse position; so I'm always loosing my location, need to scroll, then see problem 1.
3. Pasting an object drops it close to the original location, not in the area that I current see. I can move it with up/down keys, but then it gets out of the visible area, and I cannot scroll easily.

Do you know if there are solutions to these three issues, most importantly—to scrolling?

Comment: I can feel your pain... ohh. scroll bars that don't scroll. OMG.

Answer (score 1):

If you select something first, Ctrl+Mousewheel zooming keeps the selected shape centered.  While scrolling would clearly be better, you can get round it fairly quickly by Ctrl+Mousewheel zooming OUT, selecting what you want to work on next, then Ctrl+Mousewheeling back in.

Answer (score -1):

put a giant object at the edge of the slide. Can do this in slide master if there are multiple slides.

- idea from Mr Kaos

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-zooming-and-scrolling/6a77eaeb-3837-4bc4-985a-688acfc405bb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).